# text box glyphicon then a function should call

Tags: javascript, jquery, glyphicons

I am trying to call a function on textbox's glyphicon click. But i am not able to do it.

Here is my code.

```
<style>
  /* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}

/* style glyph */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
}

/* align glyph */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }


</style>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <form method="GET" class="forms-search" id="forms-search" action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('store/searcharea')?>">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="border col-sm-11 col-xs-10">
      <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
            <i id='marker' class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" style="color:#0070EB;cursor:pointer;"></i>      
              <?php echo CHtml::textField('s',$kr_search_adrress,array(
              'placeholder'=>$placholder_search,
              'class'=>"form-control",
              'required'=>true
              ))?>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color:#0070EB;color:white">Find</button>   
</div>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#marker').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
alert("hello");
});

</script>
```

Now, i wrote above code on my web page. 
i can see the marker and textbox on proper position, 
now, i want to call a function(click event) on marker click.

Can anyone tell me what is missing here.? what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like its a syntax issue. The javascript code you have in the `$(document).ready` call is improperly formatted, you do not have closing brackets and parenthesis for the outer ready function call. Change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#marker').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

I would suggest you keep your js code correctly indented to quickly recognize these syntax issues.